# SharePoint 2013 - Publish custom user profile property to User Information list using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, user-information-list

I'm using SharePoint Server 2013 and I need a powershell script that published a custom user profile property to the User Information List.

Thanks.

Comment: That would require modification to the UIL List schema, which would be inadvisable. What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: I've created a custom property which stores the user name in another language, and need to retrieve may times in many pages using rest api. I've done that by consuming data from user profile by this take significant amount of time

Comment: Consuming it through the UPA would be the correct route. Have you moved the User Profile Service onto your front end(s)?

Comment: You should just need to mark the User Profile Property as Replicable. If you can't get it let me know and I'll post code as an answer.

Comment: It's a development environment, so all services are on the same server.
@MatthewMcDermott : I've marked it as Replicable and started both User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization and Quick Synchronisation Timer jobs but nothing happened. Could you post your code please ? Thanks.

Comment: Have you updated content on the target site collection? Your users have to be "Active" for the replication to work.

Comment: @Matthew : I'm not sure that I understand well, what do you mean by : users have to be "Active" ?

Comment: They have to interact with the site by adding content or some other interactions. There is a hidden flag on the UIL that is set when a user is "Active", then the sync jobs update the info.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott : It finally worked, I found the new property replicated in all the UILs and could get the data using REST api. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great! Can I get an answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just need to mark the User Profile Property as Replicable. If you can't get it let me know and I'll post code as an answer. You also have to update content on the target site collection? Your users have to be "Active" for the replication to work.They have to interact with the site by adding content or some other interactions. There is a hidden flag on the UIL that is set when a user is "Active", then the sync jobs update the info.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, for my case, just making the UP property as Replicable did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Great, I left the rest of the explanation because it hangs folks up from time to time.

Comment: Hi Mathew , I have created one custom property and marked as Replicable but it is not showing in User Information List. could you please guide over it.

Comment: There is no guide. You mark it as replicable, populate the data and wait. There is a timer job that does the sync.